# Order of sass files loaded using webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass

**Directory Strucure**

```
->src
  ->sass
    ->home.scss 
    ->about.scss 
    ->main.scss
  ->js
    ->home.js
    ->about.js
    ->index.js
->index.php
->package.json
->webpack.config.js
```

**index.js**

`import '../sass/main.scss';`

**home.js**

```
import './index';
import '../sass/home.scss';

console.log('this is home');
```

When I run webpack, the entry point is home.js, so it creates **home.styles.css**. Inside that file, the code from home.scss is concatenated before main.scss, when it's supposed to be the other way around.

Like so: 
**home.styles.css**

```
/* content of home.scss */
/* content of main.scss */
```

I want main.scss to be concatenated first. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the ability to use `@import` to control the order of sass files was deprecated. You could try using an earlier version of sass, or see if there are more alternatives [here](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/451)